# why my test project doesn't appear on test explorer

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012 (v110)
I create a simple dll application with only 1 function and a test project to test the dll function. I set up both projects to be debug builds for win32 and tried Clean and Rebuild both projects but I don't see any test to be run on the test Explorer windows.

I also reference Dll project in the test project already.

Why isn't there anything shown in Test Explorer windows?

Comment: How would we know? Post some code.

Comment: I have a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031728/test-explorer-empty-in-vs2012-after-update-2

Comment: The code is C++, VB.Net or C# ?

Comment: @user1916893 yes, I have the same issue, I don't know what the heck it is caused by

Comment: Note that the TestClass has to be public in order for the Test Explorer to display it

Answer (score 4):

Actually MSTest doesn't work with simple class library projects.
You will have to create a unit test project and place your tests there.

If you use other testing frameworks like NUnit, then you can use plain class library. You can then use NUnit to run the tests outside VS, or use tools like ReSharper to run those tests inside VS

Comment: Thanks, I am writing unit-tests for unmanaged C++ and I have no idea why test methods never show up in Test Explorer

Comment: If you have accidentally made your project a class library instead of a unit test library and want to change it without recreating the project, go here: https://www.pmichaels.net/2017/04/02/convert-standard-c-project-unit-test-project/

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have used some test frameworks other that MSTest. If you want to use Test Explorer for some other frameworks you should install its runner too. for instance NUnit needs to install its test adapter as and extension in VS.NET

see [here for more](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.3).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify an existing class library project to get mstest to recognize it as a test project by modifying the ProjectTypeGuids in the .csproj file as detailed in this answer [How to get VS2010 to recognize my mstests generated by SpecFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469436/how-to-get-vs2010-to-recognize-my-mstests-generated-by-specflow)  (Look for the answer that lists the specific guids and not the currently accepted answer which says to just create a new project.)

Answer (score 0):

Have had a simular problem. Solved it. I have been adding tests project to my VS 2012 solution and tests were not appearing in Test Explorer. Problem was that test project was located in IIS inetpub\wwwroot folder which didn't have windows user rights to modify it. Adding solution folder Windows user rights to modify it solved issue. Tests are now visible in test explorer and able to be debugged. I assume that vstest.discoveryengine.exe process with is run by windows user was not having access to test project files