# VS2013 All tests are not appearing in test exlorer

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I have two projects in my solution which contains tests. I have tried clean build of solution but tests from only one project are appearing in the Test Explorer. I have also checked that Test->Test Settings->Default Processor Architecture is matching with that of project build settings (i.e. x86).

Comment: Is the test runner configured to use any filters? For example, you can filter for tests named "UnitTests", or that have a trait of "IntegrationTest", that kind of thing,

Comment: No, I am not using any filters. I have recently upgraded to VS2013 and I haven't added any plugin yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I set Project build settings to Any CPU it works but for any other settings (even when it matching with Test->Test Settings->Default) it fails to detect the unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

By default the Tests window will only show MsTest tests. If you have written your tests in Nunit you will need to install the '[Nunit Test Adapter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d)' Visual studio extension for it to recognize those.

Comment: +1 for reminding to check what framework is being used to write tests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ["Kristian Kristensen's"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508813/kristian-kristensen) answer to a similar question here: 
 [How to get VS2010 to recognize my mstests generated by SpecFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469436/how-to-get-vs2010-to-recognize-my-mstests-generated-by-specflow/4747845#4747845)

It worked for me.